# MooTools - AJAX refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Tags: mootools

Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

I get this error on Chrome when running a request by ajax (MooTools 1.1) ?

How to solve it ?

Comment: Please post an example over at http://jsfiddle.net, and paste back the link.

Comment: he's accepted 18 of 40, it's the placebo effect of asking about it that counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue was due to a Mootools 1.12
>   bug where it is trying to set a
>   protected value during an Ajax
>   request.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

References: http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/topic?id=1076&p=1#p4038